# Class cast Exception is being thrown while using singleton design pattern in CustomAdapter

Tags: android, listview, singleton, classcastexception

I have got a listview with custom adapter. My custom adapter utilizes two different model classes namely `ShipmentMasterDao` and `ShipmentStatusDao`.

So I have used a Singleton class called `ShipmentStatus Singleton` to return  `ShipmentMasterDao object` and `ShipmentMasterDao object`

Within my custom adapter im accessing the methods of `ShipmentMasterDao` and `ShipmentStatusDao` using the singleton class that I have created previously but it returns in class cast exception error.

Following is my singleton class,

```
public class ShipmentStatusSingleton  {

    private ShipmentMasterDao shipmentMasterDao;
    private ShipmentStatusDao shipmentStatusDao;

    private static ShipmentStatusSingleton ourInstance = new ShipmentStatusSingleton();

    public static ShipmentStatusSingleton getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private ShipmentStatusSingleton() {
    }

    public ShipmentStatusSingleton(ShipmentMasterDao shipmentMasterDao) {
        this.shipmentMasterDao = shipmentMasterDao;
    }

    public ShipmentMasterDao getShipmentMasterDaoInstance() {
        ShipmentMasterDao shipmentMasterDao = new ShipmentMasterDao();
        return shipmentMasterDao;
    }

    public ShipmentStatusDao getShipmentStatusDaoInstance() {
        return new ShipmentStatusDao();
    }
}
```

in my custom adapter and within getView method, Im invoking the methods as follows,

```
ShipmentStatusSingleton item = listForView.get(position);

        mViewHolder.mstatus.setText(ShipmentStatusSingleton.getInstance().getShipmentMasterDaoInstance().getStatus());
        mViewHolder.mDate.setText(ShipmentStatusSingleton.getInstance().getShipmentStatusDaoInstance().getDate())
```

The problem is that, it fires class cast exception on `ShipmentStatusSingleton item = listForView.get(position);`

Following is the error log,

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vaighai.model.ShipmentMasterDao
>   cannot be cast to com.vaighai.singleton.ShipmentStatusSingleton
>                                                          at com.vaighai.adapters.StatusAdapter.getView(StatusAdapter.java:84)
>                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2627)

My adapter code is as follows,

```
public class StatusAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private View view;
    private ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<ShipmentStatusSingleton> listForView;

    public StatusAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList list) {
        super();
        mContext = mContext;
        listForView = list;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listForView.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listForView.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    //Viewholder class to contain inflated xml views
    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView mstatus, mDate;
        private ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        view = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            //inflate the view for each row of listview
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.status_progress, null);
            //ViewHolder object to contain myadapter.xml elements
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            mViewHolder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.progressIcon);
            mViewHolder.mDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            mViewHolder.mstatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status);

            view.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        ShipmentMasterDao shipmentMasterDaoInstance = ShipmentStatusSingleton.getInstance().getShipmentMasterDaoInstance();
        ShipmentStatusDao shipmentStatusDaoInstance = ShipmentStatusSingleton.getInstance().getShipmentStatusDaoInstance();

        ShipmentMasterDao item = listForView.get(position);

        mViewHolder.mstatus.setText(ShipmentStatusSingleton.getInstance().getShipmentMasterDaoInstance().getStatus());
        mViewHolder.mDate.setText(ShipmentStatusSingleton.getInstance().getShipmentStatusDaoInstance().getDate());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your adapter code?

Comment: What is `listForView.get(position);` returning?

Comment: in your adapter you used masterdao singleton and when fetching data you are using status singleton that's why you are getting class cast exception

Comment: i have posted my adapter code

Comment: listForView.get(position) gets the position

Comment: using `ShipmentStatusSingleton item = listForView.get(position);` creates class castexception while ` ShipmentMasterDao item = listForView.get(position);
` works fine but when i access the getStatus method, it returns null